# How to check for multi strings in a line

Tags: python

I am trying to check for multiple strings in a line,am trying to do the following but the check fails when the line contains 'Change-Id' or 'N/A',please advise

```
line = 'N/A'
if (('Change-Id|N/A') not in line):
    print line
else:
    print "line check failed"
```

Comment: Will the line always exactly equal the strings you're checking for? Or are you testing for substrings? If you're testing entire strings, you can do `if line not in ['N/A', 'Change-Id']`, otherwise you'd be best suited with an `or` statement. Unless your test strings are complicated, in which case you might need regex.

Comment: @brittenb - the strings am checking for is a substring of the line